# Social media DIV issue

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm making my own Blogger Theme but I have a little problem with the social media bar. [Here you have a direct link to my blog](http://edlpdaniela.blogspot.com.ar/). As you can see, the bar is not shown correctly. Here you have the CSS Code

```
/* Buttons */

#social {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
  background-color:#D8D8D8;
}


#soc {
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right:10%;
}
```

And here you have the HTML Code

```
  <div id='social'> 

<center>

<div id='soc'> 


    <div class='facebook'><a href='http://www.facebook.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Facebook-icon.png'/></a></div>
    <div class='twitter'><a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Twitter-icon.png'/></a></div>
    <div class='youtube'><a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Youtube-icon.png'/></a></div>
    <div class='google'><a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Google-plus-icon.png'/></a></div>
    <div class='blogger'><a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Blogger-icon.png'/></a></div>
    <div class='instagram'><a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Instagram-icon.png'/></a></div>
    <div class='reddit'><a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Reddit-icon.png'/></a></div>
    <div class='linkedin'><a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/flat-social-media/96/Linkedin-icon.png'/></a></div>

    </div> 

    </center>

</div>
```

I tried adding the css `height:auto;` to #social but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to #social

```
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Since you wish to have them stay within the grey area of #social you need to make it resize accordingly. This is why using min-height or anything else to set a fixed height will not work.

Comment: It looks like this on my browser, which is Chrome too: [link](http://oi59.tinypic.com/70j9n8.jpg). It's like the social icons are overlapping the next div (the one with the background)

Comment: Oh so you want them in the grey part?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be in the grey part

Comment: Try adding the following to #social
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
check out main answer post

Comment: @DiseñosWeb add this it will work even when you resize the browser

Comment: I would not suggest using min-height as it is not responsive and is a set variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using min-height: 30px; forcing the height to be a minimum of 30 PX? In my experience to you have to have display:block; for this to work properly

```
 #social { 
 display:block;
 width: 100%; 
 min-height:30px; 
 padding-top:30px; 
 padding-bottom:30px; 
 background-color:#D8D8D8;
   }
```

If the diversity is not responsive like the rest of the page you may have to add more to your css such as

```
 #social { 
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin:auto;
 width: 100%; 
 min-height:30px; 
 padding-top:30px; 
 padding-bottom:30px; 
 background-color:#D8D8D8;
   }
```

I'm not at my computer to test this however

Comment: Sorrel Where do I have to add those styles?

Comment: This code is perfect, thank you so much, but when you zoom in the page, the div isn't flexible with the social icons, I don't know if you understand what I'm trying to say, If you didn't let me know and I'll try to be more descriptive. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you mean that they are not responsive? Resizing with zoom?

Comment: Yes, all of the other elements are OK when you zoom in except for the social media div.

Comment: Maybe this will help, have updated the post but I'm not at my computer to test it sadly just on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Both your social and soc have issues.  Both have a rendered height of 0px.

The social icons are Okay, the problem is you just say you have "a little problem".  It is not clear what it is you would like to improve. It appears to me your bigger problem is with the "underpoststxt" class.  But I do not know how you want it to behave as the width of the Browser changes.  When the Browser window width gets down to 700px is when it goes to hell in FireFox.

On mobile, there are no social icons.  You say zoom is a problem.  I associate zoom with mobile.  On the desktop the icon are very responsive. At a window width of 1263px they are all in one line.  At 1262 the Link In drops down next to the text in "underpoststxt".

What do you want it to do?  Your social icons are larger than they need to be IMHO.

Comment: when you zoom in the page, the div isn't flexible with the social icons

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="social">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-behance-square"></i></a>
    <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).